# Concatenate/merge columns

Tags: awk, sed, concatenation

File( ~50,000 columns)

```
A1 2 123 f f j j k k  
A2 10 789 f o p f m n
```

Output

```
A1 2 123 ff jj kk  
A2 10 789 fo pf mn
```

I basically want to concatenate every two columns into one starting from column4. How can we do it in awk or sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in awk. See below

```
:~/t> more test.txt
A1 2 123 f f j j k k

:~/t> awk '{for(i=j=4; i < NF; i+=2) {$j = $i$(i+1); j++} NF=j-1}1' test.txt
A1 2 123 ff jj kk
```

Sorry just noticed you gave two lines as example...

```
:~/t> more test.txt
A1 2 123 f f j j k k
A2 10 789 f o p f m n

:~/t> awk '{for(i=j=4; i < NF; i+=2) {$j = $i$(i+1); j++} NF=j-1}1' test.txt
A1 2 123 ff jj kk
A2 10 789 fo pf mn
```